# Can PHP threading increase speed for AJAX requests?

Tags: php, ajax, multithreading, curl

I'm creating a PHP based system for gathering and storing data, which I'm getting from multiple resources online.

My controlling page performs AJAX-requests to an server-internal PHP-file, which uses cURL to request data from different websites. Everything is working fine, but I really need to increase the speed.

My system seems to handle 6 parallell request, which seems likely to be limited by my browsers maximum number of http-connections. Chrome and Safari seems to be the same.

I've been reading a bit about PHP threading, but never used it. I'm not sure if I want to sink my teeth into it at this point if it won't help me in this project.

1. Would I gain speed from creating multiple threads with PHP?
2. Is there any other way to increase the number of parallell requests
   handled?
3. (Is it possible to manually raise the number of open connections in Chrome?)

Comment: How are you handing off requests to PHP?  Through Apache?  Through IIS/ISAPI or FastCGI?  A custom PHP webserver?

Comment: Good question. During development I'm running a local XAMPP server, which I haven't done any serious configuration on, so I guess I'm using Apache.

Comment: It's likely that you already have it configured to act in parallel using XAMPP.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340349/514087

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't see any real performance gains doing this as AJAX calls are asynchronous by default.

Comment: Yeah, but isn't it just multiple http-request in the same thread? In that case, I don't see why I couldn't increase speed buy using multiple threads as well?